# How to type a React.createContext for typescript, which takes a ref and a setState function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error (amongst others):

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type '() => void'
```

I have basically this:

```
import React, {
  ReactElement,
  ReactNode,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
  useContext,
} from 'react';

export const ScrollToContext = React.createContext({
  ref: React.createRef(),
  setScrollTo: () => {},
});

export function useScrollTo() {
  return useContext(ScrollToContext);
}
```

I want the value of the context provider to have 2 properties: a `ref`, and a `setScrollTo` which is a setState function. How do I type those in TypeScript?

How do I properly initialize `React.createContext`, and how do I type the `useScrollTo()` return value?

```
export function useScrollTo(): ??? {
  return useContext(ScrollToContext);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interface to specify the types of the context. Try this:

```
interface IScrollToContext {
  ref: RefObject<undefined>;
  setScrollTo: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>; // I am assuming the state type is a string
}

// Now you can initialize it without errors
export const ScrollToContext = createContext<IScrollToContext>({
  ref: createRef(),
  setScrollTo: () => {},
});
```

You don't need to specify the return type of the `useScrollTo` function hook. Typescript infers the type for you. But if you want to do it explicitly, do this:

```
export function useScrollTo(): IScrollToContext  {
  return useContext(ScrollToContext);
}
```